# How to rewrite `example.com/some/directory/path` to `archive.example.com/some/directory/path`

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Working on a site redesign. In the meantime, I've built a landing page at `example.com` and moved the original site to `archive.example.com`.

I'd like all url's with a path to redirect to the archived site and retain the path.

`example.com/any/directory/path` -> `archive.example.com/any/directory/path`

Obviously I don't want `example.com` to redirect.

Update: I also need `example.com/admin` to *not* redirect

Comment: My thinking was to apply this in my `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a better way to accomplish this, but the following is working for me in my `.htaccess` file.

```
# These redirect subpages to the archive site - ORDER MATTERS
RedirectMatch 302 (/asset-type(.*)) https://archive.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 302 (/about-us(.*)) https://archive.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 302 (/news(.*)) https://archive.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 302 (/portfolio(.*)) https://archive.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 302 (/services(.*)) https://archive.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 302 (/development(.*)) https://archive.example.com/$1
RedirectMatch 302 (/investment(.*)) https://archive.example.com/$1
```